# Print the file name with another extension (Batch-program)

Tags: windows, batch-file, path, syntax

Batch-program launchs with 1 parameter (full path to file)

```
program.cmd "C:\Path\To\File\Filename.txt"
```

Now, this program consists of 1 command:

```
echo %1
```

And it just prints an argument: `C:\Path\To\File\Filename.txt` for the upper example.

But I want it to print an argument (full path) with another extension, e.g. `.exe`. For the upper example, I want it to print `C:\Path\To\File\Filename.exe`.

How to make it do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%~dpn1.exe
```

Comment: This answer works, but it's not particularly descriptive. Use of the tilde magic variables would be `echo %dpn1.ext` you could also do `echo %dpn1.%2` and then use `changeext.bat foo.txt bar` and have the output `foo.bar` see: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx for magic variable references.

Answer (score 0):

In your program.cmd, you can just write commands as you would normally use them at the command prompt.

Comment: Please, read again, I tried to explain more clearly.